# What's a word meaning somebody who does things that are publicly noticeable?

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to come up with a synonym for "outspoken" with a connotation of "makes a scene about something in public", but I can't find it.

Comment: Were [all these](http://thesaurus.com/browse/outspoken) really completely unacceptable?

Comment: I looked there first, but couldn't find one I liked. Most of them like "unequivocal" were about attitude and not volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps "drama queen"? That might overemphasize the melodramatic aspect, but it's all I can think of or find. Synonyms of the term all emphasize the melodrama aspect as well, so no luck there.

Answer (score 1):

*[Uncouth](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uncouth#Adjective)* (in “Unrefined, crude” sense),  *[unrefined](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unrefined)* (“(of a person) lacking refinement; uncouth”), and  *[gauche](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gauche#Adjective)* (“Awkward or lacking in social graces”) are good possibilities.

Also consider *boorish, oafish, swinish, churlish, philistine, coarse, common* and *mannerless* (from [onelook.com](http://www.onelook.com/?w=%2a&loc=revfp2&clue=boorish)) and *[boisterous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boisterous#Adjective)* and *[raucous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raucous#Adjective)*.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually settled on **indiscreet**, having realized that I had used it before. But I'm always open to better suggestions.

Comment: A little thesaurus exploration around the words "conspicuous" and "show-off" might help, too.

Comment: I know it's your question so you know best what you're seeking, but **indiscreet** seems like an understatement compared to the behavior described in your question.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg Overly conspicuous, perhaps?